# Using Areas with RedirectToAction leads to endless loop of redirects

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

In my ASP.NET Core MVC 2.2 project I'm using areas to facilitate a better structure of classes, views etc. However, I face the following problem when redirecting from one controller to another via RedirectToAction.

I have an area called "Dashboard", a controller called DefaultDashboardController and a HomeController. 
The DefaultDashboardController is part of the Dashboard Area. The HomeController does not have an Area assigned.

Within the DefaultDashboardController there is an Index Method which only returns a view.

Now what I'm trying to do is to redirect from the Index Method of the Home Controller to the Index Method of the DefaultDashboardController.

My HomeCntroller looks like this:

```
public class HomeController 
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "DefaultDashboard", new { Area = "Dashboard"});
    }
 }
```

My DefaultDashboardController looks like this:

```
[Area("Dashboard")]
public class DefaultDashboardController 
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
 }
```

My routing configuration is setup like this in the Startup class:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapAreaRoute(
          name: "AreaDashboard",
          areaName: "Dashboard",
          template: "{area:exists}/{controller=DefaultDashboard}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
        );


        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
        );
    });
```

Now when I call the Index Method of the HomeController, I am always redirected to the very same method (Home/Index) again (causing an endless loop of get / redirect requests).

The only way I was able to resolve this, was by adding an id parameter to the RedirectToAction Call:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "DefaultDashboard", new { Area = "Dashboard", id=1});
```

However, this is a very ugly, cumbersome workaround for me.

Is RedirectToAction really only supposed to work in this way? 
Or is there any fundamental issue on how I want to utlize the Area feature of MVC Core?

**Update:**

Even though I am still not 100% sure why my initial route causes a short circuit, I cam up with the following solution that works:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapAreaRoute(
          name: "AreaDashboard",
          areaName: "Dashboard",
          template: "Dashboard/{controller=DefaultDashboard}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
        );


        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
        );
    });
```

As you can see, I've added the "Dashboard" path directly to the MapAreaRoute-template.
My assumption is that the {area:exists}- and default-route wereboth evaluated by MVC Core and considered as matching routes. Then the system somehow chose the default route as the target route. With my fixed "Dashboard"-template, this is not the case anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your default route. The area route should be your default route. It already has the `:exists`, constraint on that route param, so it will work for non-area routes as well. The routing infrastructure short-circuits, so the default route without the area will be preferred.

Comment: I don't understand why the routing infrastructure short-circuits. Isn't a route like Area=Dashboard, Controller=DefaultDashboard and Action =Index perfectly matching my first route? My understanding is that {area:exists} is a placeholder for the specified areaName (in my case: Dashboard) and therefore only the first route can match.

Comment: Nope, because technically area is not required to route. The only required things are a controller/action or page. Once it has that, then it's good to go. It's seems backward, I know, but this behavior is actually a feature. It makes routing highly efficient - but you have to be careful with your routes.

Comment: Ok, so that means he does not check the routes in a particular order? Or in other words: Both my routes fit the pattern and ASP.NET chooses the default route? If so, why does my workaround with id=1 work?